# Show status bar with animation causes view to move up 20px so its under the status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I have a UIViewController that shows and hides the status bar. Hiding the status bar works no problem, however when I show the status bar using:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO                                         withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

Causes the contents of the View to move up 20px so it ends up under the status bar. I dont know what else I can provide but this description, all that happens is when I hide the status bar, there is 20px of white space at the top where the status bar would be (this is what I want) but when I show the status bar the view moves up under the status bar (this is not what I want). The desire is to show and hide the status bar without effecting the UIViewController and its contents.

Comment: Does the content of the view move because of top layout guide constraints?

Comment: @ThatGuy Possibly. The status bar is present when the view first loads ( With the top layout constraint set to 0, there is approx 20pt of space at the top so the view is not hidden behind it) but based on an action the status bar will disappear. The status bar will slide up out of view, but the 20pt space at the top will remain (as desired) but when the status bar slides back in, the view slides up 20 pts, so there is no more white space (not desired) :(

Comment: @ThatGuy I cleared the constraints and that was definitely it. I would like to add autolayout however

Comment: @ThatGuy see my own answer below, your suggestion def pushed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by removing auto-layout on this ViewController and manually set the views layout in :

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Seems to solve the issue. Cheers to @ThatGuy for pushing me in the right directions.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I managed to fix it in the Storyboard.

The top constrain for the view that was shifting up was set to **Top Layout Guide**. I changed it to point to **Superview.Top** and the view stopped moving.

To explicitly use Superview over top layout guide, you need to use the Pin (button on bottom left corner of storyboard) and before setting up the constrain uncheck "Constrain to margins"

Comment: This fixed it for me too! i'm using swift 3 / xcode 8  and am doing interactive animated transitions between views with and without a status bar, and was having the view moving up issue. 
I had tried lots of programatic like moving the view down 20 px in an animation block, setting the content insets, etc but none of those worked. Constraining to the superview worked perfectly!

Comment: I found that IB makes it hard to constrain a view to the superview in Xcode 8, everything wants to constrain your views to the top layout guide instead.  The reliable way i found to constrain to the superview was: click the 'align' button on the right side of bottom bar of the storyboard view.  select "center vertically in container" and then double click the constraint itself and change superview.centerY to superview.top and yourView.centerY to yourView.top.

Comment: Isn't this going to break on iphone X?